# hide an item in the parent based on the data in the child loop in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, loops, angular-ng-if

I have the following HTML code snippet where i am looping through my json response to display the data. It is a nested loop with *ngIf as in the HMTL below. What i need is based on the value of one of the items in the child loop i want to hide/show an item in the parent loop.

Basically i have ***mtr.eu*** inside the child loop which is an input type.Initially it will be empty and when the user enter any value in it, i want to show the item in the parent shown below. What would be the best suitable way to achieve this.

```
    <div class="row accordian-head" accordion-heading>
        <span class="w20">MPRN: {{header.gpr}}</span>
        <span class="w20">Meter ID: {{header.num}}</span>
        <span class="w20" *ngIf="mtr.eu">New data added</span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordian-inner-content">
        <table class="table table-borderless">
            <thead>
                <tr class="meter-reading-header">
                    <th scope="col">Last read date</th>
                    <th scope="col">Last meter read</th>
                    <th scope="col">New reading (kWh)</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let mtr of header.mtrs" class="meter-reading-content">
                    <td>{{mtr.lrd}}</td>
                    <td>{{mtr.lrv}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" name="newReading" class="form-control new-reading-input"
                            placeholder="eg. 12345" [(ngModel)]="mtr.eu">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</accordion-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the child variables in the parent node. Instead, you can make a getter where you can check the records which has mu value. based on that getter value you can show the record on the parent element.

The only thing you need to do is write a function and pass your list of items into it. inside that use filter to check for required data(in your case its mt.mu). then return the data. Based on returned data you can show the element.

But when you call any function from the template it calls the function recursively.

So as a best practice I would prefer using pipes to do the same logic. Which makes my code much better.

I hope this helps you to achieve your need.